# How can I overwrite my xlsx sheet data with new data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

Below is my code
**Ws**-Contains redundant data while 
**wsRemDup**-contains data after removing the redundant/duplicate data.
wsRemDup is an array of JSON.

I want to overwrite my ws sheets data with wsRemDup.
I googled to find a way but most of the stuff showed how to append instead of overwriting it.
How can I proceed?

```
                    ws = XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, ticketNameArr,{origin:-1, skipHeader:true});
                   //Contains unique ticket name and their other fields
                    wsRemDup=removeDuplicate(ws)
                   console.log(wsRemDup)
                    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'DailyTicketSatus.xlsx')

                    respond.render('index', { "ticketNameArr": ticketNameArr });
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to overwrite the sheet on your original workbook like so:

```
const excelFile = "tickets.xlsx";
const sheetName = "Sheet1" // <-- Change to the actual sheet name.
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(excelFile);
const ws = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
let sheetJson = removeDuplicate(ws);

// Overwrite worksheet
workbook.Sheets[sheetName] = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(sheetJson);
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, excelFile);
```

Comment: It works partly. It overwrites the header as well. Added to that it doesn't overwrite on every loop(Promise).

Comment: Great, thank you for testing the answer! Now I'll modify to try to resolve point 1. (It overwrites the header). I will look at point 2. (It doesn't overwrite on every loop.)

Comment: I've updated the answer: I've removed the args to json_to_sheet, I believe this should resolve point 1.

Comment: You might clarify point 2: It doesn't overwrite on every loop. Is this code block contained in a loop of multiple files or something like that? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. The second issue too got resolved with this code.

Comment: Great, very glad to help. Good luck with the project!